# Why is list comprehension faster than setting the size of an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following three functions:

```py
def without_initialising_size():
    x = []
    for i in range(100_000):
        x.append(i)
    return x

def with_initialise_size():
    x = [None] * 100_000
    for i in range(100_000):
        x[i] = i
    return x

def list_comprehension():
    return [i for i in range(100_000)]
```

I can see why `with_initialise_size` would be faster than `without_initialising_size`.
Since we determine the size of the list we need initially, Python doesn't need to keep finding bigger blocks of memory as the list grows.

But why is `list_comprehension` significantly faster than `with_initialise_size`?

Below are the benchmarks for each method when I used the `timeit.timeit` function with number set to 1000:

**`without_initialising_size`**: 3.85671530000036

**`with_initialise_size`**: 3.0115716999971482

**`list_comprehension`**: 2.278098400001909

It is because with `with_initialise_size` there is the extra step to load `None` to each array item or is there something else that I might be missing?

Comment: Yes, you are spending an extra step to create an list of 100,000 `None`s and then modifying it in-place. All of that is expensive (the in-place modifications too have a cost).

Comment: You create a list of 100k `None`s then loop 100k times re-assigning values... (so effectively making 100k `__setitem__` calls... which is just more work than what the list-comp has to do)

Comment: Also, note that Python lists **are not arrays**. For an array, modifying the thing at position N takes a constant amount of time because you can just do some simple addition to find the memory address and change what's at that address. That is not true for lists. Python does have an array type, but you aren't using it in this code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In what sense is that not true for Python lists?

Comment: @KellyBundy I think the difference being made here is that Python lists are implemented as a sequence of pointers and store data-via-pointer (so it involves some indirection to change the stored data) whereas the Python `array` module implementation behaves like C arrays.

Comment: @wkl That's true, but that's really not what Charles makes it sound like. Makes it sound like it's a linked list or so. It *does* take only constant time for lists as well.

Comment: Hmm, I feel that list's are indeed stored as arrays. See below (sorry can't get line breaks to work):

```python

>>> x = []


>>> getsizeof(x)

72

>>> x.append(1)

>>> getsizeof(x)

104

>>> x.append(1)

>>> getsizeof(x)

104

>>> x.append(1)

>>> getsizeof(x)

104

>>> x.append(1)

>>> getsizeof(x)

104

>>> x.append(1)

>>> getsizeof(x)

136
```

The fact that the size increased after the first insertion and didn't increase for a couple inerts does suggest that it is using arrays and that it needed a bigger array later.

Comment: @SalaahAmin Python's list implementation is (in CPython) is basically an array-of-pointers (if you're familiar with C syntax, the actual Python list is a struct of `PyObject **`), with some additional stuff to support behaviors like reallocation/resizing.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense, I thought what @CharlesDuffy meant that lists in Python are just linked lists.